# PHP relative link not working as expected

Tags: php, relative-path

I'm struggling with a relative link to a .php file.  The file contains my initialise code.  It's working perfectly on the top-level pages but I just cannot connect on pages with a sub-folder. I have read and reread so many tutorials but can't get it to work.

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  try {
        require_once('./private/initialise.php');
        $years = YearsInBusiness();
?>
```

Folder Paths:

**SiteFolder/private/initialise.php** -- Location of file to link connect to.

**SiteFolder/index.php** ---Connects perfectly using path provided.

**SiteFolder/fabrication/laser-cutting.php** ---How do I reach initialise.php from laser-cutting.php file as nothing has worked?

I have tried:

```
'private/initialise.php'
'/private/initialise.php'
'./private/initialise.php'
'../private/initialise.php'
'./../private/initialise.php'
'../../private/initialise.php'
'../../../private/initialise.php'

+ Morse code!
```

Comment: I would recommend that you read up on the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) and then use a [router](https://packagist.org/?query=router) to handle the URL's (which you set up in your application.) It's how most frameworks and CMS's do it. One benefit with it is that you can change the URL's without moving the files around, and you don't need to call the initialization script manually like this since that can be in the front controller.

Comment: "How do I reach this file" - what do you mean by "reach"? The code you've shared does not include `laser-cutting.php` in any way yet

Comment: Thank you Nico.  I have now edited the statement for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dirname](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) with the [FILE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php) magic constant. Using the second parameter for the `dirname` function you can specify how many levels you want to go "up".

For example:

`require_once(dirname( __FILE__, 2) . "/your-folder/your-file.php");`

Comment: Thank you so much!   Changed from 2 to 1.  That resolved it! Thanks!